# Implementing HLS in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, http-live-streaming

I am trying to implement **[HLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming)** in action script for an audio player. Are there any open source APIs which i could use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty big project. I have done it myself twice. The only open source version I can think of is osmx. But your millage may vary.